# Webhook for Jenkins without credentials in URL

Tags: url, jenkins, gitlab, credentials

I've got a webhook setup in GitLab to detect whenever changes are pushed to the project repo. This works as needed, however the URL in use contains my Jenkins credentials and I'd like to make this more secure. e.g.:

`https://username:password@jenkins.url.com/project/git-project`

Is there a way to generate a token of sorts in Jenkins instead of providing my username and password?

Comment: are you using your local host for jenkins server?

Answer (score 0):

There are access tokens in GitLab, you can use it. From Jenkins part, you can install GitLab plugin and then add new credentials for SSH and GitLab API Token. Please see [this](https://jamalshahverdiev.wordpress.com/2018/02/07/jenkins-gitlab-integration-with-webhook/) and [this](https://medium.com/@teeks99/continuous-integration-with-jenkins-and-gitlab-fa770c62e88a) for more details.